# 'vector<vector<int> >' cannot be initialized with an initializer list in VS Code while c++11 is in settings.json

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-code

I have recently started learning C++ and am using Visual Studio Code for it. I have been starting to transfer a Python `non-aggregate type 'vector<vector<int> >' cannot be initialized with an initializer list` while trying to declare a 2D matrix with `std::vector`. When I looked online to see how others fixed this problem, it said that this kind of error often is raised when versions of C++ older than C++11 are used, and followed the instructions given to instruct Visual Studio Code to use the argument `-std=c++11` when compiling the program. However, this did not change anything, and I now have no idea on how to fix the error.

Code:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<int> > board = {
    {0,0,3, 0,9,2, 0,0,0},
    {4,0,0, 0,3,0, 0,1,0},
    {2,7,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0},

    {0,1,0, 3,0,0, 0,0,8},
    {0,5,0, 1,6,7, 0,3,0},
    {3,0,0, 0,0,8, 0,6,0},

    {0,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,5,3},
    {0,3,0, 0,8,0 ,0,0,9},
    {0,0,0, 6,2,0, 1,0,0}
};

vector<vector<int> > get_square(int x, int y, vector<vector<int> > grid) {
    int norm_x = floor(x / 3) * 3;
    int norm_y = floor(y / 3) * 3;
    vector<vector<int> > square = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            square[i][j] = grid[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    return square;
};

int main() {
    int test1[2][2] = {
        {1,2},
        {3,4}
    };
    int test2[2][2] = {
        {0,0},
        {0,0}
    };
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            test2[i][j] = test1[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    test2[0][0] = 0;
    cout << test1 << "\n";
    cout << test2 << "\n";
    vector<vector<int> > result;
    result = get_square(1,1,board);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            cout << result[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
};
```

settings.json (`code-runner.executorMap`):

```cpp
"code-runner.executorMap": {


    
        "javascript": "node",
        "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -std=c++11 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "objective-c": "cd $dir && gcc -framework Cocoa $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "php": "php",
        "python": "python -u",
        "perl": "perl",
        "perl6": "perl6",
        "ruby": "ruby",
        "go": "go run",
        "lua": "lua",
        "groovy": "groovy",
        "powershell": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File",
        "bat": "cmd /c",
        "shellscript": "bash",
        "fsharp": "fsi",
        "csharp": "scriptcs",
        "vbscript": "cscript //Nologo",
        "typescript": "ts-node",
        "coffeescript": "coffee",
        "scala": "scala",
        "swift": "swift",
        "julia": "julia",
        "crystal": "crystal",
        "ocaml": "ocaml",
        "r": "Rscript",
        "applescript": "osascript",
        "clojure": "lein exec",
        "haxe": "haxe --cwd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash --run $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "rust": "cd $dir && rustc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "racket": "racket",
        "scheme": "csi -script",
        "ahk": "autohotkey",
        "autoit": "autoit3",
        "dart": "dart",
        "pascal": "cd $dir && fpc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "d": "cd $dir && dmd $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "haskell": "runhaskell",
        "nim": "nim compile --verbosity:0 --hints:off --run",
        "lisp": "sbcl --script",
        "kit": "kitc --run",
        "v": "v run",
        "sass": "sass --style expanded",
        "scss": "scss --style expanded",
        "less": "cd $dir && lessc $fileName $fileNameWithoutExt.css",
        "FortranFreeForm": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran-modern": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran_fixed-form": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
    },
```

Terminal error output:

```
Build finished with errors(s):
path/to/file/sudoku.cpp:7:22: error: non-aggregate type 'vector<vector<int> >' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
vector<vector<int> > board = {
                     ^       ~
path/to/file/sudoku.cpp:24:26: error: non-aggregate type 'vector<vector<int> >' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
    vector<vector<int> > square = {};
                         ^        ~~
2 errors generated.

The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).
```

I would appreciate if the answer provided a clear explanation for the solution, as I do not have much experience with C++. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9aacccbbbcf74980)

Comment: Have you added -std=c++11 to your tasks.json file?

Comment: Have you tried compiling from the command line, to see if this is a compiler issue, or a visual studio code issue?

Comment: @john thank you! adding to tasks.json solved the problem (really haven't had the chance to explore these files so not very experienced with them and editing them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried changing the `args` in your `task.json` file? It should more or less, look like this.

```
"args": [
          "-g",
          "-std=c++11",
          "${file}",
          "-o",
          "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
```

Anyways if you're going to use Visual Studio Code for C++, I suggest doing C++ work in a WSL environment instead and compile via the terminal. Debugging might be tedious with GDb but you can use https://www.onlinegdb.com/ as an alternative.

Comment: Thank you!! This is what I was looking for for so long.